# EllipseGeometry element bind Image element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**l want show a circle image**

first l write this code:

```
<Image
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Source="111.png"
            Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.Clip>
                <EllipseGeometry
                    Center="25,25"
                    RadiusX="25"
                    RadiusY="25" />
            </Image.Clip>
        </Image>
```

then l try bind value between image and ellipseGeometry,
by this way l need set a name to Image like this code

```
<Image
            x:Name="img"
            Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Margin="163,178,579,191"
            Source="111.png"
            Stretch="Fill">
            <Image.Clip>
                <EllipseGeometry
                    Center="25,25"
                    RadiusX="{Binding Width, ElementName=img, Converter={StaticResource tohalfConverter}}"
                    RadiusY="{Binding Height, ElementName=img, Converter={StaticResource tohalfConverter}}" />
            </Image.Clip>
        </Image>
```

**now its my problem:** if l do not set a name to Image,how to bind value between Image and ellipseGeometry? l try use FindAncestor but its failed.

Answer (score 0):

Better fill an Ellipse with an ImageBrush.

The ImageBrush automatically fills the Ellipse area according to the value of its Stretch property.

```
<Ellipse Width="50" Height="50">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="111.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: thanks its good answer. but how to bind value between Image and ellipseGeometry in my method?

Comment: That's not necessary. The ImageBrush will scale automatically.